# how to calculate percentage of different rows from rows total in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a database where and i have to % wise distribute orders by order type ?

currently i am using

```
(count(CASE WHEN TYPE='DigitalForwardOrder'then 1 end)/count(type))*100,
```

here "DigitalForwardOrder" is one of the value in rows and "type" in the column name

Answer (score 0):

A more concise formulation uses `avg()`:

```
avg(case when TYPE = 'DigitalForwardOrder' then 100.0 else 0 end)
```

Or even more concisely in Postgres:

```
avg( (type = 'DigitalForwardOrder')::int ) * 100
```

Comment: i want to find the % but it still gives me value as 100 and i have 7 different values but all i am getting is 100 but i want to calculate % for all of these rows seperataly .

eg : DigitalForwardOrder is in 100 rows 
and there are 1000 rows in type column so i want 10% as the answer .

Comment: @sahil-learner . . . Can you set up a db<>fiddle illustrating this?